# webkit browsers: white flashes on transitions between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

Is there a solution or a workaround for the long lasting problem in webkit browsers, which is a white flash on loading a page? You should see the issue on this page: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/

I am interested in what might be a cause and how to (at least partially) resolve this.

Related links:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45640.

Comment: Usually this is a specific error on your website, such as a script not loading immediately. If you post your code, we can probably help you. Try moving all of your script tags to the end of the page.

Comment: @David: I can't currently provide my code. I have at least linked a page where a problem also occurs.

Comment: This doesn't help. You need to provide the code relevant to your problem. It is not a cookie-cutter solution. At least provide a link to the page where the problem occurs.

Comment: I've noticed lately (read: last six months or so) that the Webkit rendering engine has been, for lack of a better term, a bit shit. I can be in the middle of typing a post on my forums, for example, when the entire window goes crazy flashing, revealing windows behind - and you better hope those windows don't have harmful buttons right where you try to click in Chrome when it happens!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving all the javascript just before the closing body tag resolved the issue.